# is after_update triggered when creating a new record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is the `after_update` callback triggered when creating an ActiveRecord object?

Comment: Can you share your tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The after_create and after_update callbacks are called on new and persisted record respectively.

The after_save callback is called both when a record has been created and updated.